# Neo4j Sink not recieving Kafka Topic events

Tags: neo4j, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, neo4j-apoc

I have used docker compose to set up an instance of Neo4j with the streams plug in and the apoc procedures. Code is below:

```
neo4j-sink:
    image: neo4j:3.5
    hostname: neo4j-sink
    container_name: neo4j-sink
#    depends_on:
#      - neo4j-source
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
       - ./neo4j/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      NEO4J_kafka_zookeeper_connect: 0.0.0.0:2181
      NEO4J_kafka_bootstrap_servers: 0.0.0.0:9092
#      NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/sink
      NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max_size: 2G
      NEO4J_kafka_max_poll_records: 10000
      NEO4J_dbms_logs_debug_level: DEBUG
      NEO4J_streams_sink_enabled: "true"
      NEO4J_kafka_group_id: "neo4j_sink_1"
      NEO4J_enable_auto_commit: "true"
      NEO4J_streams_sink_topic_cypher_ARTICLECOMMIT: "WITH event.value as payload MERGE (a:Article {id: payload.ID}) ON CREATE set a.descr = payload.og_description"
```

This has led to the sink initialising and listening to the topic:

```
neo4j-sink    | 2019-09-14 09:45:54.962+0000 INFO  Starting the Kafka Sink
neo4j-sink    | 2019-09-14 09:45:55.473+0000 INFO  Creating Sink daemon Job
neo4j-sink    | 2019-09-14 09:45:55.478+0000 DEBUG Subscribed topics with Cypher queries: {ARTICLECOMMIT=WITH event.value as payload MERGE (a:Article {id: payload.ID}) ON CREATE set a.descr = payload.og_description}
neo4j-sink    | 2019-09-14 09:45:55.479+0000 DEBUG Subscribed topics with CDC configuration: {CDC_SOURCE_ID=[], CDC_SCHEMA=[]}
neo4j-sink    | 2019-09-14 09:45:55.480+0000 INFO  Kafka Sink started
neo4j-sink    | 2019-09-14 09:45:55.480+0000 INFO  Streams Sink module initialised
```

however from the command line producer OR when I send a message through my stream, it does not register in neo4J. I can confirm that the topic is recieving messages from my streams; I checked through the Kafka-console-consumer and listening in the stream. Please advise if there is anything I am doing wrong.

I tried this:

```
$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list 0.0.0.0:9092 --topic ARTICLECOMMIT
>{"ID":12345,"og_descrpition":"12312312"}
```

which is the most basic attempt thatpublishes to the topic. but no event received to neo4j. Can someone help

Answer (score 0):

I think there's probably two things wrong. First, I believe your Cypher is incorrect - you're not posting an event with a `payload` property, just one with an `ID` and `og_description` at the top-level. The following seems more likely to work:

```
NEO4J_streams_sink_topic_cypher_ARTICLECOMMIT: "MERGE (a:Article {id: event.ID}) ON CREATE set a.descr = event.og_description"
```

However, if that were the only thing wrong you'd see errors in your logs similar to:

```
neo4j-sink | 2019-09-16 10:56:39.543+0000 ERROR Error while executing the query Cannot merge node using null property value for id
```

Since you don't mention seeing any errors, the most likely candidate is that the plugin isn't actually listening on the topic but has failed silently. I encountered this locally trying to replicate the issue.

To check, I would use

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server 0.0.0.0:9092 --list --all-groups
```

You should see `neo4j_sink_1` as a registered consumer group. If you **don't**, there's a config issue - most likely from what I've seen that your Kafka instance isn't actually listening on port 9092 with host 0.0.0.0.

The following `docker-compose.yml` is what I've gotten working locally, which spins up a 1-node Kafka cluster and Neo4j using a modified version of your Cypher query:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 1
        ZOO_PORT: 2181
        ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888    
    volumes:
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/data:/data
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/datalog:/datalog

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.0
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1    
    volumes:
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zoo1

  core1:
    image: neo4j:3.5
    hostname: neo4j-sink
    container_name: neo4j-sink
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - ./core1_plugins:/plugins
      - ./core1_logs:/logs
    environment:
      NEO4J_kafka_zookeeper_connect: zoo1:2181
      NEO4J_kafka_bootstrap_servers: kafka1:19092
      NEO4J_kafka_group_id: "neo4j_sink"
      NEO4J_kafka_group_instance_id: "neo4j_sink"
      NEO4J_streams_sink_topic_cypher_ARTICLECOMMIT: "MERGE (a:Article {id: event.ID}) ON CREATE set a.descr = event.og_description"
      NEO4J_dbms_logs_debug_level: DEBUG
      NEO4J_streams_sink_enabled: "true"
      NEO4J_streams_procedures_enabled: "true"
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
```

One final note - [there's a breaking issue with version 3.5.3](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-streams/issues/230) of the Neo4j Streams plugin that'll cause an exception upon startup once you've gotten the Kafka configuration right. I used [version 3.5.2](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-streams/releases/tag/3.5.2) to avoid the regression, and there's a patch coming up in the next release apparently.